# Class does not exist octobercms

Tags: queue, classnotfoundexception, jobs, octobercms, octobercms-plugins

I'm new in `october cms` and I want to push a job in queue but when I writing bottom code in my controller, I got error for class not exist !
I already create my class in classes folder of plugin ...

```html
       Queue::push('\Mori\News\Classes\Insta', ['message' => "hello"]);
```

[place of file that i made](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRtg9.png)

the error I got:

> Class \Mori\News\Classes\Insta does not exist
>   **\xampp\htdocs\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php line 752

How could I solve this issue?

Comment: Can you please provide your Insta class code?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are missing `jobs` folder

code should be like this

> Queue::push('\Mori\News\Classes\**Jobs**\Insta', ['message' => "hello"]);

according to your pic it seems it is `inside jobs folder` so just add it as well.

if any doubt please comment.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try first **composer dump-autoload**. If not work then **composer update** command may be your issue was solved.